# Parsing highly nested JSON in pySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I was trying to parse/read following nested JSON in pyspark dataframe.
This fails even when pyspark infers schema or when I am passing schema to it.

Im running this AWS EMR cluster

```
{ 
"coffee": {
    "region": [
        {"id":1,"name":"John Doe"},
        {"id":2,"name":"Don Joeh"}
    ],
    "country": {"id":2,"company":"ACME"}
}, 
"brewing": {
    "region": [
        {"id":1,"name":"John Doe"},
        {"id":2,"name":"Don Joeh"}
    ],
    "country": {"id":2,"company":"ACME"}
}
}
```

Pyspark itself is unable to parse the schema and throws following error.

```
    An error occurred while calling o745.json.
: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.http.AbstractHttpFileSystem.listStatus(AbstractHttpFileSystem.java:91)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.http.HttpsFileSystem.listStatus(HttpsFileSystem.java:23)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Globber.listStatus(Globber.java:77)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Globber.doGlob(Globber.java:235)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Globber.glob(Globber.java:149)
............
............
............

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 274, in json
    return self._df(self._jreader.json(self._spark._sc._jvm.PythonUtils.toSeq(path)))
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
    answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
    format(target_id, ".", name), value)
```

I did try by passing my own schema which is below

**code:**

```
c1_schema= StructType([StructField("id",IntegerType()), StructField("name",StringType())])
region_schema= StructField('region',ArrayType(c1_schema))
country_schema= StructField('country',StructType([StructField("id",IntegerType()), StructField("company",StringType())]))t_schema= StructType([StructField("coffee",StructType([region_schema,country_schema])),StructField("brewing",StructType([region_schema,country_schema]))])

df3= spark.read.option("multiline", "true").json(path1,t_schema)
```

Comment: Would you consider flattening the schema?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is perfectly fine unless your JSON has issues. Here is my version (I'm using Spark 3.1.1 locally)

```py
obj = '''<your entire json above here>'''

# write to file
path1 = 'obj.json'
with open(path1, 'w') as f:
  f.write(a)
  f.close()

# your exact schema here
c1_schema= StructType([StructField("id",IntegerType()), StructField("name",StringType())])
region_schema= StructField('region',ArrayType(c1_schema))
country_schema= StructField('country',StructType([StructField("id",IntegerType()), StructField("company",StringType())]))
t_schema= StructType([StructField("coffee",StructType([region_schema,country_schema])),StructField("brewing",StructType([region_schema,country_schema]))])

# your exact dataframe here
df3 = spark.read.option("multiline", "true").json(path1,t_schema)
```

And results

```
# df3.printSchema()
root
 |-- coffee: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- region: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- id: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- country: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- id: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- company: string (nullable = true)
 |-- brewing: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- region: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- id: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- country: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- id: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- company: string (nullable = true)

# df3.show(10, False)
+-------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------+
|coffee                                     |brewing                                    |
+-------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------+
|{[{1, John Doe}, {2, Don Joeh}], {2, ACME}}|{[{1, John Doe}, {2, Don Joeh}], {2, ACME}}|
+-------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: right, even I can run this code. 
There seems something on AWS's EMR